# How to prevent user from selecting locked cells in excel using Apache poi library?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI library to protect excel sheet, I am keeping some cells unlocked and locking rest of the cells, additionally I am hiding some columns. But when user select all columns using CTRL+A he/she can copy all data including hidden columns as well.

I found one way in excel which prevents user from selecting protected cells, below is the snapshot for same.

[image]

removing tick from "Select locked cell" will prevent user from selecting protected cell, but I am not able to find the method to do the same in code.

How to do this in code using Apache POI?

I am using below code to read workbook object .

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(FILE_PATH));
```

I am able to hide columns, protect sheet and unlock columns, Now I want to prevent user from selecting locked cells.

Comment: [XSSFSheet.lockSelectLockedCells](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#lockSelectLockedCells-boolean-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Workbook object, XSSFWorkbook and XSSFSheet   allows many controls which I wanted.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook )WorkbookFactory.create(new File(FILE_PATH));
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(SHEET_NAME);
sheet.enableLocking();
sheet.protectSheet(SHEET_PROTECT_PASSWORD);
sheet.lockSelectLockedCells(true);
```